# Changing tabs in Angular Material using Cypress

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress, angular-material-tab

I have an Angular Material tab group on my page. I have to test changing of tabs using Cypress. When the page loads the user is on the **Basic Information** tab, I want to switch to the **Relationships** tab. I am not able to change the tabs

Here's the code:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">

  <mat-tab label="Basic Information">
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab data-cy="relationship-tab" label="Relationship" *ngIf="leiType.value===leiTypes.CORPORATION">
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab label="Address">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I am using the click event on the label to change the tab, but to no avail.

```
cy.get(`[data-cy='relationship-tab']`).click();
// cy.get(`[data-cy='relationship-tab']`).trigger('click');
```

I get the following error:

```
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: [data-cy='relationship-tab'], but never found it.
```

Answer (score 3):

Hence the mat-tab is not rendered to the DOM one-in-one, you should consider other options. As of now, the `mat-tab` is included in the DOM like this:

`<div role="tab" ... >`

So if you are on a page where you do not have any other div's with role tab, you can select this based on cypress css selector, with the following set-up.

```
// Select second tab
cy.get('div[role=tab]').eq(1).click();
```

By the way, relying only this css selector is not in the best practices, but I hope I was able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished that by

cy.get('.mat-tab-label').contains('Relationship').click()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How about waiting the tag to be visible and then clicking on it, this works for me always:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="relationship-tab"]').should('be.visible');    
cy.get('[data-cy="relationship-tab"]').click();
```

Comment: what is the error you see, if is timeout how about to  change  in cypress.json file: "defaultCommandTimeout" : 7000

Comment: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: [data-cy='relationship-tab'], but never found it.

Comment: put the data-cy attribute into double quotes, like in my answer, it might interpret the single quotes wrong

Comment: Tried, didn't work :( I failed to mention that the angular-material tabs are in angular material dialog when opens when user clicks a button. Could this be the issue?

Comment: went through the rendered HTML code in the dev tools and noticed that Angular Material changed the code. There wasn't any <mat-tab data-cy="relationship-tab">. Achieved the required functionality using .mat-tab-label-content

Comment: @SanjaPaskova I generelly do `cy.get("[data-cy=exportUserData]").should("be.visible");` and that works fine so I think you won't need additional single or double quotes.